# Azure AD B2C ROPC Flow Error in iOS (Swift 4) - Resource owner flow can only be used by applications created through the B2C admin portal

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to implement Azure AD B2C ROPC Flow into an iOS Swift 4 application. I've already I've followed the instructions found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc) and in this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-appauth-ropc). I've replaced the following request parameters:

```
kIssuer: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Tenant Name}.onmicrosoft.com/{Signin Policy Name}/v2.0"
kIssuerROPC: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/{Resource Owner Policy Name}/v2.0"
kClientId: "{Application ID}"
kRedirectUri: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/oauth2/nativeclient"
```

My `additionalParameters` is as follows:

```
"[
    username": "{test email account}",
    "password": "{test password}",
    "scope": "openid {kClientId} offline_access",
    "response_type": "token id_token
]"
```

I'll perform the method `OIDTokenRequest` as such:

```
OIDTokenRequest(
    configuration: configuration!, 
    grantType: OIDGrantTypePassword, 
    authorizationCode: nil, 
    redirectURL: redirectURI!, 
    clientID: self.kClientID, 
    clientSecret: nil, 
    scope: additionalParameters["scope"], 
    refreshToken: nil, 
    codeVerifier: nil, 
    additionalParameters: additionalParameters
)
```

I print out the following message:

```
"Performing ROPC with request [%@] <OIDTokenRequest: 0x6000002a17a0, request: <URL:https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_ropc_auth/oauth2/token, HTTPBody: password=TESTPW&response_type=token%20id_token&scope=openid%KCLIENTID%20offline_access&scope=openid%20KCLIENTID%20offline_access&refresh_token=offline_access&grant_type=password&username=TESTEMAIL&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/oauth2/nativeclient&client_id=KCLIENTID>>
```

where I've coded out TESTEMAIL, TESTPW, and KCLIENTID as mentioned in my first two sets of parameters.

I'm getting this **error**:

`Token request error: "unauthorized_client: AADB2C90248: Resource owner flow can only be used by applications created through the B2C admin portal.`

I'm using the application's `kClientId` that I've registered in Azure AD B2C and it's showing up 3 different times in the request URL. I've tried various combinations of parameters, but this is the furthest I can get.

The only part that I can potentially think of that is not working properly is that the `kRedirectUri` in the example is `msalb35a3d9b://oauth/redirect`, and step 4 in this [documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-appauth-ropc)
specifically says to change a `info.plist` value to `msalb35a3d9b`.

In my AADB2C registered application, I have 2 `RedirectURIS`:

`urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/oauth2/nativeclient`

I've added `urn:ietf:wg` to the `info.plist`, but nothing works. I still get the same error.

Can someone help me get around this effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the configuration that worked for me.

```
let clientId = "{Application ID}"
let authorizationEndpoint = URL(string: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p={ROPC Policy Name}")
let tokenEndpoint = URL(string: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p={ROPC Policy Name}")
let redirectUri = URL(string: "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob")

let configuration = OIDServiceConfiguration(authorizationEndpoint: authorizationEndpoint!, tokenEndpoint: tokenEndpoint!)

let additionalParameters = [
        "username": "{Username}",
        "password": "{Password}",
        "scope": "openid {Application ID} offline_access",
        "response_type": "token id_token"
    ]

let tokenExchangeRequest = OIDTokenRequest(configuration: configuration, grantType: OIDGrantTypePassword, authorizationCode: nil, redirectURL: self.redirectUri!, clientID: self.clientId, clientSecret: nil, scope: nil, refreshToken: nil, codeVerifier: nil, additionalParameters: additionalParameters)
```

Then perform the request for the token.

```
OIDAuthorizationService.perform(tokenExchangeRequest, callback: { tokenResponse, error in
        if tokenResponse == nil {
            print("Token request error: %@", error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        } else {
            print("Received token response with accessToken: %@", tokenResponse?.accessToken as Any)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your hitting the V2 endpoint, otherwise you will get the error you are seeing.

Try:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_ropc_auth/oauth2/**V2.0**/token

Comment: I tried using your suggestion as the `kIssuer`, `kIssuerROPC` and the `kRedirectURI` to no success. I get this error now: `Error retrieving discovery document: %@ Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed.`

Comment: You should just need to change / check kIssuerROPC. As this is what is used to determine the Metadata URL which is where it grabs the token endpoint from. As long as that is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/{Resource Owner Policy Name}/v2.0` you should be fine. By the look of the log you give though it is not hitting the V2.0 endpooint.

Comment: When I created the ROPC policy, it generated an endpoint that contained all sorts of configuration metadata. I used the info there regarding the authorization endpoint and token endpoint to fill in the AppAuth configuration. The token request exchange does not include the issuer endpoint.